# How can I add a <thead> section to a marionette collectionview with tagName: 'table'?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a collection view that looks something like this:

```
var PersonView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName: 'tr',
        template: function (model) {
            return _.template("<td><%= data.firstName %></td><td><%= data.lastName %></td>", {
                firstName: model.firstName,
                lastName: model.lastName
            }, { variable: 'data' });
        }
    }),
    PersonCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        tagName: 'table',
        itemView: PersonView
    });
```

It works fine, but I can't figure out the best way to add a `<thead>` section to my table. I thought of changing `tagName: 'table'` to `tagName: 'tbody'` and adding the `thead` section in the layout which displays the collection view, but it doesn't look like a very clean approach. Indeed, if I were to use my collection view elsewhere, I would have to reproduce the `thead` section in another layout... What is the proposed way of doing this?

P.S See https://github.com/shawninder/table-collection-views for a working example. You'll notice the table has no `<thead>` section, which is what I'm trying to solve.

UPDATE: Fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/shawninder/table-collection-views/commit/10a9c0a8f167e7104af7cba3776691466acb23af) based on accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use the [CompositeView](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md) instead. With `CompositeView` you can provide a template which adds your `thead` and use the `ItemViewContainer` to render you collections. Read the [doc](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md) and I am sure you will figure out the solution.

Comment: `childViewContainer` for Marionette 2.x, and CompositeView is going away in favor of LayoutViews in Marionette 3.x